# Missing Controller not reading dropbox add function Cakephp Getting View Model not found

Tags: cakephp, controller, action

I have the follow code in my Controller, which is getting values from the dropbox chooser.

```
<?php class DropboxboxfilesController extends AppController {

  public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->input('json_decode');
        $this->Dropboxfile->create();
        if ($this->Dropboxfile->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your file has been liberated :)'));
            $this->redirect($this->referer());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Something went wrong!'));
        }
    }
}}?>
```

However, when I am getting the error that the add function does not exist when I hit submit on the submit button for the chooser.

I have tried several things but nothing seems to be working so far.

EDIT: 
View code

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Dropboxfile', array ('array' => 'file')); ?>
<input type="dropbox-chooser" name="selected-file" style="visibility: hidden;"/>  
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Finish'); ?>
```

The dropbox code I am using https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js

EDIT

```
<form action="/cake/homes" array="file" id="DropboxfileIndexForm" method="post" accept-    carset="utf-8"><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></div><input type="dropbox-chooser" name="selected-file" style="visibility: hidden;"/>  
<div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Finish"/></div></form
```

Comment: Provide the code of the form you created in view file.

Comment: and Dropboxfile  model source code

Comment: Can you inspect the resulting form code and post the html that php generates for that?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong format for your second argument in $this->Form->create(). Notice how, in your parsed form element, it has an invalid 'array="file"' element and the action does not lead to the add action. Try this instead:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create(
    'Dropboxfile', 
    array(
        'url' => array('action' => 'add'),
        'type' => 'file'
    )
);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I realized that it wasn't parsing the file and was able to fix it. I am just trying to get the JSON responses from dropbox chooser and parse that information. I am not getting an information from the form.